# Correcting margin or padding in CSS for iPhone - TouchFolio theme for Wordpress

Tags: iphone, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a personal live site at http://brunomoreira.net based on the great Touchfolio theme (http://dimsemenov.com/themes/touchfolio/) for Wordpress.
Since I don't know LESS, I've changed it to use a regular style.css stylesheet.
Everything looks fine except when viewing the "Projects List" (http://brunomoreira.net/projects-list/) section on a iPhone. The masonry blocks appear slightly padded to the right and that makes them not appear 100% visible on the iPhone screen (and it lets me swipe to the right, which shouldn't be possible).
I believe it may be a problem with margins or padding in the CSS or in the masonry code itself, but can't figure it out.
Any help appreciated, 
thanks.
Bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the mobile version you should remove the padding from:

```
#primary { padding: 0!important; }
```

Comment: Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction (used 0 for padding for all except top).